# Asynchronous processing with loading spinner to update two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `Index View` which contains a table of 'Exceptions' and beneath this table I am rendering a `Partial View` which contains another table but this time with 'Resolved Exceptions'.

On the `Index View` I have a button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Exceptions", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" }))
{
    <input id="btnAutoMatch" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Run Auto Match" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Everytime this button is clicked, some logic will run which attempts to move as many Exceptions to the Resolved Exceptions but at the moment the page will postback once finished processing to get the new data:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost()
{
    AutoMatcher matcher = new AutoMatcher(_service);
    matcher.AutoMatchExceptions(User.Identity.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**What I need**

The above works perfectly well however what I now need to improve the user experience as when this process is invoked they have no idea what is going on.

This processing can take approx. 1-30 seconds depending on how many Exceptions there are, instead of the screen going white while it loads & post's back, I want this to be done Asynchronously and while it processes and have a loading spinner pop up and then disappear once the async processing has finished.

This is the kind of spinner I am looking for:

http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

I have tried swapping `Html.BeginForm` for `Ajax.BeginForm` but was not really sure what I needed the `UpdateTargetId` to be as I have 2 tables which need to be updated.

Comment: Hi, You can also register OnSuccess callback in Ajax.BeginForm helper, there you can do anything you want with data returned (update tables etc). LoadingElementId field contains id of an loading element, in your case it is a spinner.

Comment: You'll want to use an ajax request to track the progress of the request.